# How to get html with javascript rendered sourcecode by using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I run a query in one web page, then I get result url. If I right click see html source, I can see the html code generated by JS. If I simply use urllib, python cannot get the JS code. So I see some solution using selenium. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://www.archives.com/member/Default.aspx?_act=VitalSearchResult&lastName=Smith&state=UT&country=US&deathYear=2004&deathYearSpan=10&location=UT&activityID=9b79d578-b2a7-4665-9021-b104999cf031&RecordType=2'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\python27\scripts\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get(url)
print driver.page_source

>>> <html><head></head><body></body></html>         Obviously It's not right!!
```

Here's the source code I need in right click windows, (I want the INFORMATION part)

```
</script></div><div class="searchColRight"><div id="topActions" class="clearfix 
noPrint"><div id="breadcrumbs" class="left"><a title="Results Summary"
href="Default.aspx?    _act=VitalSearchR ...... <<INFORMATION I NEED>> ... 
to view the entire record.</p></div><script xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".ancestry-information-tooltip").actooltip({
href: "#AncestryInformationTooltip", orientation: "bottomleft"});
        });
```

So my question is: How to get the information generated by JS?

Comment: What does the html code you want look like on the page? You will want to use one of selenium's `get_element_by_*` functions, but how exactly depends on the html itself.

Comment: I mean everything. For example, you enter something in google. In the result webpage, right click, see source. That's the "everything" I want.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You will need to get get the document via `javascript` you can use seleniums `execute_script` function

```
from time import sleep # this should go at the top of the file

sleep(5)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
print html
```

That will get everything inside of the `<html>` tag

Comment: It's looks work, but only gives me <html><head></head><body></body></html>, I redefined my question there, could you take a look at the question again please? THank you very much

Comment: @MacSanhe see my edits, if the page is not fully loaded you will not get all the body content. Also try going to the page and running in your debugger console,  `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` to see how much of the DOM comes through.

Comment: Does anyone know if theres a way of getting the javascript of a page without using a browser like with Selenium?

Comment: @Wilson - you should create a top level question. Its hard to clarify and answer your question in the comments.

Comment: try to load PhantomJS with this parameters. browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
It works to me

Comment: @MacSanhe Is your problem solved? After doing this mine returns "<head></head><body></body>"

Comment: Is it possible it takes more than 5 seconds for the page to render @Vida , you wish to increase the sleep time

Comment: For those testing domains with self signed certificates with ssl errors please checkout @JongSuPark comment as it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary to use that workaround, you can use instead:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem about getting Javascript sourcecode from Internet, and I solved it using above Victory's suggestion.

***First**: `execute_script`

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(urls)
innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
#print(driver.page_source)
```

***Second**: parse html using `beautifulsoup` (You can Downloaded `beautifulsoup` by pip command)

```
 import bs4    #import beautifulsoup
 import re
 from time import sleep

 sleep(1)      #wait one second 
 root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(innerHTML,"lxml") #parse HTML using beautifulsoup
 viewcount=root.find_all("span",attrs={'class':'short-view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer'})   #find the value which you need.
```

***Third**: print out the value you need

```
 for span in viewcount:
    print(span.string)
```

***Full code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml

urls="http://www.archives.com/member/Default.aspx?_act=VitalSearchResult&lastName=Smith&state=UT&country=US&deathYear=2004&deathYearSpan=10&location=UT&activityID=9b79d578-b2a7-4665-9021-b104999cf031&RecordType=2"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()


##driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(urls)
innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
##print(driver.page_source)

import bs4
import re
from time import sleep

sleep(1)
root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(innerHTML,"lxml")
viewcount=root.find_all("span",attrs={'class':'short-view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer'})


for span in viewcount:
print(span.string)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

I am thinking that you are getting the source code before the JavaScript has rendered the dynamic HTML.

Initially try putting a few seconds sleep between the navigate and get page source.

If this works, then you can change to a different wait strategy.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL If the sleep works for you, you now may wish to implement a more stable wait strategy; e.g. wait until an specific element is displayed

Using "sleep" is an inherently  unstable

Comment: thank you Robbi, it is indeed what I did with:

`myclass = 'question'`    `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, myclass)))`

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and finally solved by desired_capabilities.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType

proxy = Proxy(
     {
          'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
          'httpProxy': 'ip_or_host:port'
     }
)
desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
proxy.add_to_capabilities(desired_capabilities)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
driver.get('test_url')
print driver.page_source
```

Comment: it's an old and slightly outdated answer but it gave me an idea on catching javascript with mitmproxy, so +1

Comment: But what if you need to click an element or enter text?

Answer (score 1):

You try `Dryscrape` this browser is fully supported heavy js codes try it i hope it work for you

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer