# How to crawl 'hidden' JS for locally saved html

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am using selenium & scrapy for a project.

I need to have a local html file and this is why I am locally downloading the html by using 'driver.page_source' with selenium and saving it as a local .html file.

When I open it in any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), I see that not all of the page is displayed. However, if I open the same file in notepad, textedit, or Pycharm it displays all the information. Also, if I look at the source code (in Chrome or any other browser, the information appears).

I have tried to follow the advice on many feeds:
For e.g.:  by implementing: 
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"). But that doesn't work
  (e.g.: [How to get html with javascript rendered sourcecode by using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514/how-to-get-html-with-javascript-rendered-sourcecode-by-using-selenium))

IMPORTANT: Actually, when I first open the local html file, I can briefly see the whole page before it 'disappears'.

After many days of being baffled, I would truly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What code do you have so far? Please share.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider the question alecxe! :-D  I have found a solution to the problem (explained below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution to the problem.

What I did was disable JS in Firefox.driver (in webdriver) and it works just fine. This has been on my mind for the past several weeks. Underneath is the code to do that in Python.

I hope that this can help someone else out. It took me a long time to find the Python code for it - There were plenty of Ruby and Java answers out there. Unfortunately I cannot find the source of my answer any more.

Enjoy! :-D

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```