# How can I retrieve the information of an ajax function in Selenium with Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium

I have a code, that it's not mine, and I have to make a test with Selenium for that code.

The problem that I have it's that the web application have ajax functions (that I didn't see before) and they are refresh a part of the application all the time with data, that it's changing in each refresh. I have to retrieve this information to work with them in the project with Java.

Searching by the Internet I found that ajax it's `Asynchronous JavaScript And XML`and that means that the information in a part of your web application can refresh without refreshing the page (correct me if I have a wrong idea).

Also I found that I need a Servlet or something like that to retrieve the information but I couldn't really understand what it's it and how I had to use it for my objective.

Anyway, I suppose that if the web application that I'm using it's retrieving data in each refresh, it would have to use some function or something to make this properly. And my doubt it's that if any of you know how it is usually retrieve (I mean the information in ajax functions) to search it in the project or if there is something like some function or method to know WHEN and WHAT data the application it's retrieving in each refresh without using the functions that I suppose that are in the code (and that I couldn't find).

Any help would be appreciated, both to clearify some information of ajax (that I put above) and to clearify how I can engage this problem.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I can't put any code here because it's the code of a third person and it's not mine. I expect you could help me.

Comment: Does the `DOM` change with each ajax call? I mean can you grab the content that comes from the `AJAX` call at least once?

Comment: @Victory Wow! I though this question will be death for years. Thanks for answer! Well... Now I don't have the code but I remember that the html of the website changed everytime I log-in on it. It's why I wanted to get .ajax info, because by xpath, javascript I couldn't and I know that these functions were displayed with ajax.

Comment: Ok so this question isn't too interesting right now so i won't go much into the different options. However if the update just happened once then something like what is posted in this answer might be enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514/how-to-get-html-with-javascript-rendered-sourcecode-by-using-selenium/22739613#22739613

Comment: @Victory Yes, don't worry now about this question but the link that you provided it's what I wouldn't be able to use because of the constant changing Html. Just now I was only curious about how it could be. Anyway, thanks for your time expended here! :)