# Python Selenium accessing HTML source - After Search

Tags: python, selenium

Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "C:\\Python27\\chromedriver\\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
# Open Chrome
driver.get("http://www.thehindu.com/")
# 10 Second Delay
time.sleep(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("searchString")
# Enter Keyword
elem.send_keys("unilever")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)

#  Problem Here
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print soup
```

Above it the code.
I want to scrap data from "http://www.thehindu.com/", It searches for "unilever"  word in search box and redirect to result page

[Link for Search Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYyD6.png)

Now I have a question for this, How can I get Source code of the searched Page.
Basically I want news related to "Unilever".

Comment: try `driver.page_source` ?

Comment: If I Get source code manually and with your method @The6thSense, different results!

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514/how-to-get-html-with-javascript-rendered-sourcecode-by-using-selenium

Comment: @shivshankar they tend to be because `selenium` run javascripts and provides the output after making necessary changes in source code just see the resemblance between them .

Comment: @KitFung, this is different

Comment: @shivshankar Have you tried the first solution in that post? Thats exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get text inside `<body>`:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
bodyText = body.get_attribute("innerText")
```

Then you can find your keyword in bodyText.