# Tricky dropdown option selection with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python and Selenium to navigate a website.

On a page, I am trying to work my way through a series of 5 dropdown boxes.  The options in each dropdown box are generated dynamically, based on what is selected from the previous dropdown(s).

I am stuck on the third dropdown, in which the user must choose a state.
When loaded, the inspected HTML looks like:

```
<select name="state" class="pulldown"  id="state" onchange="[javablob]">
<option value="">Select a State</option>
<option value='AK_N'>               AK</option>
<option value='AL_N'>               AL</option>
<option value='AR_Y'>               AR</option>
```

...and so on.

My code thus far is:

```
waitforstate = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"state")))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  #added because the ID is found but the states aren't loaded yet
state = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('state'))
```

But choosing the state I want doesn't work:

```
state.select_by_visible_text("TN")
```

gives...

```
Message: Given xpath expression ".//option[normalize-space(.) = "TN"]" is invalid: 
WrongDocumentError: Node cannot be used in a document other than the 
one in which it was created
```

Doing this:

```
state.select_by_value("TN_Y")
```

gives...

```
Message: Given css selector expression "option[value ="TN_Y"]" is invalid: 
TypeError: can't access dead object
```

There is no index to select a state from.

When I try to show what options ARE loaded:

```
all_options = state.options
for option in all_options:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
```

...nothing prints, not even the default option.  But it appears I can select and unselect the default option, using this:

```
state.select_by_visible_text("Select a State")
print "Select a state selected"
state._unsetSelected
print "Now it's unselected"
```

...which runs without errors.

I used Firefox's Selenium IDE to navigate the page, to see how it was handled, and it was able to select it with `id=state, label=TN.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find phantomjs or other webkit libraries more useful when scraping javascript-rendered pages. There ability to fully recreate web-browser interaction makes it more predictable/easy to implement scrapers.

I personally like to use selenium and phantomjs together for scraping purposes.

> phantomjs: https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/
>
> python-qt4:
> https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

Comment: Thank you.  I don't see how these tools adds functionality in this situation -- my problem is not with the scraping per se, it's navigating to the scraped pages, which require completing the dropdown forms.

Comment: I suspect the dropdown list of states are created with javascript. As I said, javascript rendered elements has to be read differently with selenium. Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22739613/5808505

Comment: Thank you. That method generates the same HTML, in this particular instance, as the method I was using. As it turns out, my error was not waiting long enough for the full javascript-generated option list to load. `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` did not wait adequately, but `sleep(5)` did.