# Selenium: How to get the html code generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Good day!
I'm new to selenium, and I'm trying to get the html code of website.

The `driver.page_source()` returns

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://bam.nr-data.net/1/c95cd51526?a=214311961&amp;v=1167.2a4546b&amp;to=ZlBXZxcAVkEHV0NbDV8aYEEMTlpXEg1dU09cWldaCQQXXglTXlxNWFtRVh1PSFoW&amp;rst=369&amp;ref=https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/bet9ja-mobile/login/&amp;ap=5&amp;be=335&amp;fe=366&amp;dc=363&amp;perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1588632697764,%22n%22:0,%22u%22:321,%22ue%22:321,%22f%22:4,%22dn%22:5,%22dne%22:5,%22c%22:5,%22s%22:94,%22ce%22:191,%22rq%22:191,%22rp%22:310,%22rpe%22:313,%22dl%22:325,%22di%22:363,%22ds%22:363,%22de%22:366,%22dc%22:366,%22l%22:366,%22le%22:367%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&amp;fp=362&amp;at=ShdUEV8aRU8%3D&amp;jsonp=NREUM.setToken"></script><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1167.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"c95cd51526",applicationID:"214311961"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,n,t){function r(t){if(!n[t]){var i=n[t]={exports:{}};e[t][0].call(i.exports,function(n){var i=e[t][1][n];return r(i||n)},i,i.exports)}return n[t].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)r(t[i]);return r}({1:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e,n,t){return function(){return o(e,[u.now()].concat(f(arguments)),n?null:this,t),n?void 0:this}}var o=e("handle"),a=e(4),f=e(5),c=e("ee").get("tracer"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],l="api-",d=l+"ixn-";a(p,function(e,n){s[n]=i(l+n,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=i(l+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=i(l+"routeName",!0),n.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,n){var t={},r=this,i="function"==typeof n;return o(d+"tracer",[u.now(),e,t],r),function(){if(c.emit((i?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[u.now(),r,i],t),i)try{return n.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],t),e}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[u.now()],t)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,n){m[n]=i(d+n)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e,n){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),o("err",[e,u.now(),!1,n])}},{}],2:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.forEach(function(e){"first-paint"===e.name?c("timing",["fp",Math.floor(e.startTime)]):"first-contentful-paint"===e.name&&c("timing",["fcp",Math.floor(e.startTime)])})}function i(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.length>0&&c("lcp",[t[t.length-1]])}function o(e){if(e instanceof s&&!l){var n,t=Math.round(e.timeStamp);n=t>1e12?Date.now()-t:u.now()-t,l=!0,c("timing",["fi",t,{type:e.type,fid:n}])}}if(!("init"in NREUM&&"page_view_timing"in NREUM.init&&"enabled"in NREUM.init.page_view_timing&&NREUM.init.page_view_timing.enabled===!1)){var a,f,c=e("handle"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM.o.EV;if("PerformanceObserver"in window&&"function"==typeof window.PerformanceObserver){a=new PerformanceObserver(r),f=new PerformanceObserver(i);try{a.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]}),f.observe({entryTypes:["largest-contentful-paint"]})}catch(p){}}if("addEventListener"in document){var l=!1,d=["click","keydown","mousedown","pointerdown","touchstart"];d.forEach(function(e){document.addEventListener(e,o,!1)})}}},{}],3:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){if(!i)return!1;if(e!==i)return!1;if(!n)return!0;if(!o)return!1;for(var t=o.split("."),r=n.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==t[a])return!1;return!0}var i=null,o=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var f=navigator.userAgent,c=f.match(a);c&&f.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&f.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(i="Safari",o=c[1])}n.exports={agent:i,version:o,match:r}},{}],4:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=[],r="",o=0;for(r in e)i.call(e,r)&&(t[o]=n(r,e[r]),o+=1);return t}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],5:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){n||(n=0),"undefined"==typeof t&&(t=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,i=t-n||0,o=Array(i<0?0:i);++r<i;)o[r]=e[n+r];return o}n.exports=r},{}],6:[function(e,n,t){n.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e){function n(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?c(e,f,o):o()}function t(t,r,i,o){if(!l.aborted||o){e&&e(t,r,i);for(var a=n(i),f=v(t),c=f.length,u=0;u<c;u++)f[u].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[t]];return p&&p.push([b,t,r,a]),a}}function d(e,n){h[e]=v(e).concat(n)}function m(e,n){var t=h[e];if(t)for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++)t[r]===n&&t.splice(r,1)}function v(e){return h[e]||[]}function g(e){return p[e]=p[e]||i(t)}function w(e,n){u(e,function(e,t){n=n||"feature",y[t]=n,n in s||(s[n]=[])})}var h={},y={},b={on:d,addEventListener:d,removeEventListener:m,emit:t,get:g,listeners:v,context:n,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function o(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(l.aborted=!0,s=l.backlog={})}var f="nr@context",c=e("gos"),u=e(4),s={},p={},l=n.exports=i();l.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){if(i.call(e,n))return e[n];var r=t();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,n,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(o){}return e[n]=r,r}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t,r){i.buffer([e],r),i.emit(e,n,t)}var i=e("ee").get("handle");n.exports=r,r.ee=i},{}],id:[function(e,n,t){function r(e){var n=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==n&&"function"!==n?-1:e===window?0:a(e,o,function(){return i++})}var i=1,o="nr@id",a=e("gos");n.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,n,t){function r(){if(!x++){var e=E.info=NREUM.info,n=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&n))return s.abort();u(y,function(n,t){e[n]||(e[n]=t)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+E.offset],null,"api");var t=d.createElement("script");t.src="https://"+e.agent,n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n)}}function i(){"complete"===d.readyState&&o()}function o(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+E.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(f=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),f))-E.offset}var f=(new Date).getTime(),c=e("handle"),u=e(4),s=e("ee"),p=e(3),l=window,d=l.document,m="addEventListener",v="attachEvent",g=l.XMLHttpRequest,w=g&&g.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:l.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:g,REQ:l.Request,EV:l.Event,PR:l.Promise,MO:l.MutationObserver};var h=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1167.min.js"},b=g&&w&&w[m]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),E=n.exports={offset:f,now:a,origin:h,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:p};e(1),e(2),d[m]?(d[m]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),l[m]("load",r,!1)):(d[v]("onreadystatechange",i),l[v]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",f],null,"api");var x=0,O=e(6)},{}],"wrap-function":[function(e,n,t){function r(e){return!(e&&e instanceof Function&&e.apply&&!e[a])}var i=e("ee"),o=e(5),a="nr@original",f=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;n.exports=function(e,n){function t(e,n,t,i){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,f,c;try{a=this,r=o(arguments),f="function"==typeof t?t(r,a):t||{}}catch(u){l([u,"",[r,a,i],f])}s(n+"start",[r,a,i],f);try{return c=e.apply(a,r)}catch(p){throw s(n+"err",[r,a,p],f),p}finally{s(n+"end",[r,a,c],f)}}return r(e)?e:(n||(n=""),nrWrapper[a]=e,p(e,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function u(e,n,i,o){i||(i="");var a,f,c,u="-"===i.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<n.length;c++)f=n[c],a=e[f],r(a)||(e[f]=t(a,u?f+i:i,o,f))}function s(t,r,i){if(!c||n){var o=c;c=!0;try{e.emit(t,r,i,n)}catch(a){l([a,t,r,i])}c=o}}function p(e,n){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var t=Object.keys(e);return t.forEach(function(t){Object.defineProperty(n,t,{get:function(){return e[t]},set:function(n){return e[t]=n,n}})}),n}catch(r){l([r])}for(var i in e)f.call(e,i)&&(n[i]=e[i]);return n}function l(n){try{e.emit("internal-error",n)}catch(t){}}return e||(e=i),t.inPlace=u,t.flag=a,t}},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Adapter</title>
    <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/login_favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/sportsbook.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700">
    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/loginBetin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="plugins/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Javascript client-side code -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lang = "";
        function openSelection(mode, uri){
            var url  = "https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com" + uri + (uri.indexOf('?') ? "&mode=" : "?mode=") + mode + "&lang=" + lang;
            window.location.replace(url);
        }

        function backToMain(){
            var url = "https://mobile.bet9ja.com/Mobile";
            window.location.replace(url);
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grapi.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="product" style="display: none">
</div>

<div class="container" id="playarea" style="">
    <script>
        var isLoaded = false;

        function onLoadIframe(iframe) {
            if (!isLoaded) {
        //      iframe.src = '?game=league&OTP=905f9407-8b82-4cf6-9d63-f7bf7fe4da6c&mode=premier&lang='; // './index-iframe-content.html' + window.location.search;
                if( iframe.src != "" )
                {
                    isLoaded = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                goBackUrl();
            }
        }

        eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        eventer = window[eventMethod];
        messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
        eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
            let data = e.data.split('$');
            let command = data[0];
            if (command == "goHome") {
                backToMain();
            }
        }, false);
    </script>

    <div style="${bet9ja.iframe.style}">
        <iframe id="playAreaFrame" onload="onLoadIframe(this)" style="
                    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;
                " src="https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/mobile-1.94.35/themes/?sk=bet9ja&amp;t=644ee448-8fb1-426c-9922-31688a0a85f6&amp;pinHash=02ba41004b38f08bf291e763d02ec2b0&amp;pid=14001&amp;v=0&amp;text=Premier&amp;homeUrl=https://mobile.bet9ja.com/Mobile&amp;otp=905f9407-8b82-4cf6-9d63-f7bf7fe4da6c&amp;ss=&amp;bl=&amp;vu=0">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        var input       = {"game":"league","OTP":"905f9407-8b82-4cf6-9d63-f7bf7fe4da6c","mode":"premier","lang":""};
        var u           = "905f9407-8b82-4cf6-9d63-f7bf7fe4da6c";
        var home        = ""; //"https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/bet9ja-mobile/login/";
        var params      = "&pid=14001&v=0&text=Premier";
        var game        = "league_premier";
        grapi.loggedUser(u,input,home,params,game,true );
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"c95cd51526","applicationID":"214311961","transactionName":"ZlBXZxcAVkEHV0NbDV8aYEEMTlpXEg1dU09cWldaCQQXXglTXlxNWFtRVh1PSFoW","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":5,"atts":"ShdUEV8aRU8=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script>
</body></html>
```

But what happens in the website, is another page will load after this one, which contains the information and numbers that I need, and when I inspect the page using Chrome I find an other html in side the previous one (this one is the one I need):

```
<html lang="en" class="ui-mobile"><head><base href="https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/mobile-1.94.35/themes/?sk=bet9ja&amp;t=644ee448-8fb1-426c-9922-31688a0a85f6&amp;pinHash=02ba41004b38f08bf291e763d02ec2b0&amp;pid=14001&amp;v=0&amp;text=Premier&amp;homeUrl=https://mobile.bet9ja.com/Mobile&amp;otp=905f9407-8b82-4cf6-9d63-f7bf7fe4da6c&amp;ss=&amp;bl=&amp;vu=0#bet"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"><link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/jquery-mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts/Icomoon/icomoon.css"><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/md5/md5.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/ejs/ejstpl.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="_base/views/views.min.1.94.35.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/lib.min.1.94.35.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="bet9ja/js/tracking.js"></script><script async="" src="//static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-243625.js?sv=5"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="bet9ja/js/certify.js"></script><link id="dynamic-favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="bet9ja/assets/favicon.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bet9ja/css/style.min.1.94.35.css"></head><body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a" style="padding-top: 0px;"><div class="panel left ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-push ui-panel-closed ui-body-inherit ui-panel-animate" data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="push" id="menu_left_panel">
    <div class="ui-panel-inner"><div class="panel-container">
        <div id="playlist-selector"></div>

        <div class="menu-container">
          <div id="deposit-now-container">
              <a href="" onclick="ViewMenu.deposit_credit()" target="IFrame" class="ui-link"> Deposit now</a>
          </div>
          <div id="deposit-now-container-min">
              <div class="deposit-now-service-container">
                  <img class="payment-img" src="_base/assets/img/mpesa_GR.png">
                  <div class="payment-text">Paybill Number</div>
                  <div class="pay-bill">997270</div>
              </div>
              <div class="deposit-now-service-container">
                  <img class="payment-img" src="_base/assets/img/airtel_GR.png">
                  <div class="payment-text">Paybill Name</div>
                  <div class="pay-bill">997270</div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div id="menu-logged-information"><table><tbody><tr>                               <td style="font-weight: bold;color:#7792B5; text-shadow: none">Logged: </td>                               <td id="nom_log" style="padding-left:20px;font-size:1.5em">3942938</td>                            </tr><tr>                            <td style="font-weight: bold;color:#7792B5">Balance: </td>                            <td style="padding-left:20px;font-weight: bold;color:#FFD326"><span id="current_balance">₦ 0</span></td>                       </tr>                       </tbody></table></div>
          <ul id="menu"><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li><li class="li_live"></li>
              <li class="li_bet"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_bet_bet" onclick="ViewInit.betButton()" title="Bets" data-rel="close" class="ui-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron icon-home3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Bet now</a></li>
              <li class="li_ticket"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_bet_ticket" onclick="ViewTicketHistory.showTicketHistory(false)" title="Tickets" data-rel="close" class="ui-link"><div id="circle-menu-ticket-id"></div><i class="fa fa-chevron icon-ticket">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><span>Tickets&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></li>


                  <li class="li_results"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_bet_results" onclick="ViewResults.showResults()" title="Results" data-rel="close" class="ui-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron icon-trophy">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Results</a></li>
                  <li class="li_league_table"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_league_table" onclick="ViewLeagueTable.showLeagueTable()" title="League Table" data-rel="close" class="ui-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron icon-calendar">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>League Table</a></li>





              <!--<li class="li_statment"><a id="a_bet_statment" onclick="$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#statements')" title="Statements" data-rel="close">Statements<i class="fa fa-chevron"></i></a></li>-->
              <li class="li_back"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_bet_bet" onclick="ViewMenu.close()" title="Bets" data-rel="close" class="ui-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron icon-arrow-left2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Close menu</a></li>

                  <li class="li_back"><a style="padding-left: 20px" id="a_bet_bet" onclick="/*window.history.back()*/ window.parent.postMessage('goHome', '*'/*window.location.origin*/);" title="Bets" data-rel="close" class="ui-link">Mobile Home</a></li>


          </ul>
          <div id="last-session-div"></div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</div><div id="loading" style="display: none;"><div id="loading-league">
    <div id="loading-div-image">
        <img id="loading-image-bar" src="bet9ja/assets/img/intro_loader.gif">
    </div>
    <div id="loading-div-error"></div>
</div>
</div><div id="bet" class="demo-wrapper ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="bet" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;"><div class="ui-panel-wrapper"><div class="header ui-header ui-bar-inherit" data-role="header" role="banner">
    <span class="open left"><a href="#menu_left_panel" class="ui-link"><i class="fa fa-bars icon-menu" style="font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 2em"></i></a></span>
    <span class="title title-header-mobile"><img class="log-image-header" src="bet9ja/assets/img/logo_1_gl.png" alt="logo">
    </span>


    <!-- BetSlip -->
    <span id="liveBetsTicket">
        <a id="bet_ticket" onclick="document.getElementById('div_button_market').scrollIntoView(true);" title="Tickets" class="ui-link">
            <i class="fa-lg fa-chevron-right pull-right icon-ticket"></i><span id="bet_ticket_matchResult_counterSelections">0</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <!-- FreeBets -->
    <div id="freeBets">
        <a id="freeBetsButton" title="Free bets" class="ui-link">
            <div class="icon-free-bets pull-right"></div>
            <span id="free_bets_counterSelections">0</span>
        </a>
        <div id="freeBetsDropdown" class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <div id="freeBetsDropdownActive" class="active-free-bets"><a class="free-bet no-items">
    <span>No available free bets</span>
</a></div>
            <div id="freeBetsDropdownInactive" class="inactive-free-bets"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div class="content ui-content" data-role="content" style="position: relative;" role="main">
    <div class="titan-content" style="display:none">
        <div class="div-xs-6 titan-group-container">
            <div class="gold-titan-text">Gold Titan</div>
            <div class="gold-titan-amount"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-xs-6 titan-shop-container">
            <div class="titan-text">Red Titan</div>
            <div class="titan-amount"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bets-bonus">
        <div class="div-xs-5 bonus-text">Bonus<span>Level: 1</span></div>
        <div class="div-xs-1 div-empty"> </div>
        <div class="div-xs-5 bonus-amount bonus-collapse">₦ 100</div>
        <div class="div-xs-1 bonus-collapse"> <i class="fafa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bets-bonus-collapsed collapsed">
        <div class="div-xs-3 bonus-text">Bonus</div>
        <div class="div-xs-1 percentage-bar-bonus-collapsed">0%</div>
        <div class="div-xs-4 bonus-amount-collapsed">₦ 100</div>
        <div class="div-xs-3 countdown-time-bonus-collapsed bonus-collapse">48h 0' 0''</div>
        <div class="div-xs-1 bonus-collapse"> <i class="fafa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bets-bonus-extended">
        <div class="countdown-bar-bonus">
            <div class="div-xs-12 countdown-bonus">
                <div class="countdown-bonus-inside" style="width: 0%;"> </div>
                <div class="circle-percentage" style="left: 0%;">0%</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="time-bonus">
            <div class="countdown-time-bonus">48h 0' 0''</div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-bonus">
            <div class="div-xs-1 div-empty"> </div>
            <div class="div-xs-10 bonus-message" style="display: block">
                Each ticket you place within the above time gets you closer to your free bonus. Once you claim your bonus your level moves up and your bonus gets higher<i class="info-bonus-hover fafa fa-info" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 5px;border-radius: 5px;"></i></div>
            <div class="div-xs-10 bonus-message-winner" style=" display: none;"></div>
            <div class="div-xs-1 div-empty"> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bets-time" style="display: block;" class=""><div class="playlist-info">
    <img class="playlist-image" height="50" width="50" src="bet9ja/assets/premier.png" alt="14001">
    <div id="bets-time-betContdown">00:34</div>
    <div>
        <span id="text-idleague">League</span>
        #<span id="idleague">5269</span>
        <span id="leagueWeek">Week <span id="leagueWeekNumber">03</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="credit-with-countdown">
    <div id="credit-countdown">₦ 0</div>
</div></div>

    <div id="loading-next-event">
        <p>Waiting next round<br>
            <img src="bet9ja/assets/img/loader_data_race.gif">
        </p>
    </div>





                       ...ect The code stills too long
```

I have tried this code:

```
premiere_legue.click() #this button takes as to page where the problem is
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
print(html) # The output is the same first code I shared
```

I believe that this has to go through a JavaScript code,

Any one can help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like the page might be rendered. This solution recommends waiting to retrieve the contents of the page [How to get html with javascript rendered sourcecode by using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514/how-to-get-html-with-javascript-rendered-sourcecode-by-using-selenium)

```
from time import sleep # this should go at the top of the file

sleep(5)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

Comment: I have updated the post with the code I tried, I have even waited 15 seconds lool

Comment: maybe a headless browser would help if you're not already using one, this gist shows how: https://gist.github.com/macloo/bc4edf018cc81ad0b0cfe59daf82c8af

Comment: Yrah that's exactly what I wan to do... I want the html code from selenium webdriver, then I want to parse it using beautifulsoup 4... But the problem is that the code is not the right one

Comment: can you say which site you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Yes sure!
it's https://mobile.bet9ja.com/mobile it needs log in.
After that clicking league in the upper bar
then Premier (top left)
An image will load then some numbers will show, I'm trying to have those number

Comment: dang! I can see the page load then then it returns the original html

Comment: Yeah that's weird!
I have been looking online for a day now... Nothing found!