# Execute a part of code after waiting for button to be clicked in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a webpage that displays some products. This webpage has around 50 products, and when i click on load more, more products are displayed. I want to extract information for all these. I have written a code for same. The problem however is, that the program proceeds with retrieving information without waiting for the button to be clicked. I have tried changing the time.sleep values to very high values, but no avail. Is there some other expression i could include to make the rest of the code wait till the button is clicked?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import xlsxwriter

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(5)

#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")))
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']"))
button.click() 

#wait.until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")))
time.sleep(10)
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")))



def cpap_spider(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-info__caption"}):
            
        href="https://www.justnebulizers.com"+link.get("href")
        #title= link.string
        each_item(href)    
        print(href)
            #print(title)

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"tab_table"})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        row_i+=1
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          # Here if you want then you can remove unwanted characters like : ? from temp
          # For example "Actual Weight" and ""
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('respiratory_care.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "href")
    
cpap_spider("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
#each_item("https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical")       
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working just fine but you need to soup the source again with...

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

...after you click the on the button to get the new items. I think that is why it looks like it is running without waiting.

There are wait methods that can be used with Selenium which you can use to ensure a condition is met before proceeding: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Also you may want to try Scrapy for crawling: https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy/

**Update:**
Try this:

Change

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

with

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser')
```

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565160/4289062

Comment: Hi. Still does not work. Only gives information for the first set of products

Comment: Updated my answer. If it still doesn't work then you'll have to post your code after changes.

Comment: still get the output for first set of products. I have updated the code. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Check and let me know.