# How to use selenium and bs4 to scrape html loaded through AJAX

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the job listings from the asda webpage, but whenever I scrape the webpage it doesn't return the elements that I am trying to scrape.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

url = "https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.get(url)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(30)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"class": "ListGridContainer"})

print(soup.prettify())
```

I tried to see if the website used infinite scrolling but I did not know how to get elements from this. Also, it keeps on returning some of the webpage but then the rest that is returned is just the javascript used to load the job listings.

Comment: Does `browser.page_source` return the original page source or what is currently on the page? That div is not present in the source.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739613/548841

Comment: Does `.find("div", {"class": "ListGridContainer"})` return `None` for you? It returns [the expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP9Ia.png) for me with the same exact code as yours. I've even expanded it into to scrape all the listings to CSV, and it's working ok.   **[see these results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-6lQzVPBBAZ1PV0dtKQZ7G4iC4nHWCZJt1i7BqRL7o)**

Comment: There are duplicates, but that might be intentional (I think glassdoor does something similar) - they only show 25 pages with 20 results per page, so you'll probably never get more than 500 of all 1k+ results via browser/selenium  [ [imxitiz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75032654/6146136) gets all the listings with no duplicates btw. ]

Answer (score 1):

I think using [https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/ajaxaction/posbrowser_gridhandler/?movejump=[requried page number - 1]&movejump_page=[requried page number]](https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/ajaxaction/posbrowser_gridhandler/?movejump=0&movejump_page=1) link will make your work easier.

Here in link, there are two parameters for determining which page should be shown.
One is **movejump** whose value would be **1 less then required page number** and another is **movejump_page** whose value would be **required page number**.

There are some cookies problem... But I have fixed it in code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/ajaxaction/posbrowser_gridhandler/?"

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/")

pagestamp=s.cookies['earcusession'][5:-8]
url=url+f"pagestamp={pagestamp}"

for i in range(3):
    page=s.get(url+f"&movejump={i}&movejump_page={i+1}")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")
    print(soup.find("div", {"class": "ListGridContainer"}).prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

url = "https://www.asda.jobs/vacancy/find/results/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.get(url)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(5)

html = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"class": "ListGridContainer"})

print(soup.prettify())
```