# Scraping a dynamic webpage where text is loaded asyncronously

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a scraper for HBR. Recently, HBR seems to have changed their site API which seems to have broken my script

Previously, when I used the following script, I could get the html for the entire article

```
url ='https://hbr.org/2023/08/mastering-the-art-of-the-request'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36"
}
# Send a GET request to the URL with custom headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
sel = Selector(text=response.text)
art =  sel.xpath('//div[@class="article-body standard-content"]//p').extract()
```

Now, when I use this code, it only seems to be pulling the first p tag, because the requests object is returning a subset of the html. I tried inspecting the network tag to see if there is any async json being loaded through an API but can't see any such call

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Try to print `response.text` to see if the article is contained within this or not. Maybe they just changed the structure of the HTML ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514/how-to-get-html-with-javascript-rendered-sourcecode-by-using-selenium link for more information about rendering javascript in selenium.

Although what i recommend is to get the API endpoints from Network tab in your browser and convert the curl command to language of your choice using curlconverter.com, this usually works if the site you are scraping doesn't use any hard identification method, and you can pass a lot of errors by simply changing headers (user-agent and etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your browsers network call, you'll see that the article is also available  dynamically through sending a `POST` request to:

```
https://hbr.org/api/article/piano/content?year=2023&month=08&seotitle=mastering-the-art-of-the-request
```

You can mimic the request as follows:

```py
import requests


params = {
    "year": "2023",
    "month": "08",
    "seotitle": "mastering-the-art-of-the-request",
}

json_data = {
    "key": "pwQMlv9Jiar79jaw1VnxLzV2uLE9CtGd7Go+FPSFnY0pGK0D1Zv/B56cSd/NKFIh31XZOkv5G5rRqRhrP7UkdWtO5TplDhkfiquLsPGg8YA=",
    "contentKey": "BM5l29iJY6Ee+8B2yfNlrdgbvN4VLOJhHh/T44P8lW63kSqFbbABFP5qz3keUVTgvIfdCZQW9kY5QAdPhYcp9g==",
    "pageSlug": "article",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://hbr.org/api/article/piano/content",
    params=params,
    json=json_data,
)

print(response.json())
```

Prints (truncated)

```
{'content': '<div class="translate-message">\n <a href="/2023/08/mastering-the-art-of-the-request?language=es" class="lang-es">Leer en español</a>\n <br>\n <a href="/2023/08/mastering-the-art-of-the-request?language=pt" class="lang-pt">Ler em português</a>\n</div>\n<p>If there was ever a time when leaders could simply issue commands and consider them done, now is most certainly not that time. We live in a world of flattened organizational structures, cross-functional teams, and workplace cultures that value collaboration, autonomy, and sensitivity. In my work coaching executives at companies and nonprofits over the past 20 years, I’ve observed....
```

Now, you can simply access the `content` key as a normal dictionary to get the HTML data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use selenium

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from scrapy import Selector

# Set up Chrome options to run headless (without GUI)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

# Provide the path to your Chrome driver executable
chrome_driver_path = 'path/to/chromedriver'  # Replace with the actual path

# Initialize the Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://hbr.org/2023/08/mastering-the-art-of-the-request'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for a few seconds to let the page load completely (you can adjust the wait time)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Extract the HTML content of the article
article_html = driver.page_source

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

# Parse the HTML using Selector
sel = Selector(text=article_html)
art = sel.xpath('//div[@class="article-body standard-content"]//p').extract()

# Now you can process the 'art' variable as needed
```